# This is about album and memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I'm using Swift, and I called once the album, with a systematic approach, and then allowed to dismiss the normal way (perhaps even less the other way), but after a call to complete systems approach, memory will rise 20M, I wrote a simple example, found that still the case, I wrote immediate window in `appdelegate`. Swift `rootViewController` switch inside, still can not eliminate this 20M memory. Because I called up a photo album directly 20M, but many times I'll call the album now, not in this demo, so I need to solve this 20M problem.

The code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        var bu = UIButton()
        bu.frame = CGRectMake(80, 80, 80, 80)
        bu.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        bu.addTarget(self, action: "hh", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(bu)
    }

    func hh() {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                var tt = TViewController()
        self.presentViewController(tt, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController){
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: What makes you think using 20M is a problem?

Comment: What's `TViewController` is about. If you see 20M of memory increase every time you call this method, maybe you have some problem in that view.

Comment: one i will up 20M,but my app open alum least 4 times , so ,it make my app memory increase 80M,and zhe TViewController is another viewController, have nothing ,just backgroundcolor is blue to make sure my code is OK